# Unable to activate the Message Processor in WSO2 EI 6.6

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb, wso2-enterprise-integrator

I can't activate the message processor in the WSO2 Management console and I try to click the activate button multiple times it does not turn on and no error shown in log please help me to sort this out.

[image: Management Console]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try the following steps?

1. Undeploy your Capp.
2. Open `Registry Browser` and go to `/_system/governance/repository/components/org.wso2.carbon.tasks/definitions/-1234/ESB_TASK/` and delete the task configuration related to the Message processor you are having issues with.
3. Delete the contents in <EI_HOME>/tmp directory and restart the server.
4. Now deploy the Capp again.

Comment: Thanks a lot Now I'm able to activate the message processor